# Add records to 1 month ahead

Tags: php, laravel

I have this code:

```
$tasks = new Task();
$tasks->text = 'Velo';
$tasks->role_id = 1;
$tasks->progress = 0.0;
$tasks->duration = 1;
$tasks->start_date = Carbon::now()->addMonth();
$tasks->parent = 0;
$tasks->type = "project";
$tasks->color = '#ccc';

$tasks->save();

$tasks = new Task();
$tasks->text = 'Auto';
$tasks->role_id = 1;
$tasks->progress = 0.0;
$tasks->duration = 1;
$tasks->start_date = Carbon::now()->addMonth();
$tasks->parent = 0;
$tasks->type = "project";
$tasks->color = '#ccc';

$tasks->save();

$tasks = new Task();
$tasks->text = 'Moto';
$tasks->role_id = 1;
$tasks->progress = 0.0;
$tasks->duration = 1;
$tasks->start_date = Carbon::now()->addMonth();
$tasks->parent = 0;
$tasks->type = "project";
$tasks->color = '#ccc';

$tasks->save();
```

How  I can add these records one month ahead? Do I need to loop? But date? How I can add records? I need every day this month to have their records.

Comment: Loop for what? Your questions are __unclear__.

Comment: If you need to loop between dates. You can use the DateTime() function to get the months. It is hard to understand what is needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need a loop and a date period to loop

```
$from = \Carbon\Carbon::today();
$to = $from->copy()->addMonth();

$period = new \DatePeriod($from, new \DateInterval('P1D'), $to);

foreach ($period as $date) {
    $tasks = new Task();
    $tasks->text = 'Velo';
    $tasks->role_id = 1;
    $tasks->progress = 0.0;
    $tasks->duration = 1;
    $tasks->start_date = $date;
    $tasks->parent = 0;
    $tasks->type = "project";
    $tasks->color = '#ccc';

    $tasks->save();

    $tasks = new Task();
    $tasks->text = 'Auto';
    $tasks->role_id = 1;
    $tasks->progress = 0.0;
    $tasks->duration = 1;
    $tasks->start_date = $date;
    $tasks->parent = 0;
    $tasks->type = "project";
    $tasks->color = '#ccc';

    $tasks->save();

    $tasks = new Task();
    $tasks->text = 'Moto';
    $tasks->role_id = 1;
    $tasks->progress = 0.0;
    $tasks->duration = 1;
    $tasks->start_date = $date;
    $tasks->parent = 0;
    $tasks->type = "project";
    $tasks->color = '#ccc';

    $tasks->save();
}
```

You can also simplify the loop

```
$tasks = ['Velo', 'Auto', 'Moto'];

foreach ($period as $date) {
    foreach ($tasks as $task) {
        $task = new Task();
        $task->text = $task;
        $task->role_id = 1;
        $task->progress = 0.0;
        $task->duration = 1;
        $task->start_date = $date;
        $task->parent = 0;
        $task->type = "project";
        $task->color = '#ccc';
        $task->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: And in database I will have records on 1 month ahead?

Comment: Yes. One month ahead from your application server time.

Comment: I need record these records in the database on one month ahead.

Comment: It will save to the database one month ahead from your application server time. If your server date is 2018-01-01 it will set the `start_date` to 2018-02-01

Comment: No. I need write records to database on one month ahead. I need have 3 records per day on database. Today is 23. I don't have records, I need have, and tomorrow I need have records e.t.c

Comment: 3*30 = 90 I need have all records 90 per month.

Comment: So you need to insert the 3 tasks for the period starting from today up to a month?

Comment: Yes. I need have 3 tasks per day.

Comment: See the updated answer. It should do that. Continue this in chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169577/discussion-between-chanafdo-and-jadasdas

Comment: Ok. I am there.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of scenerio you can laravel mutators.

Here is an example

```
 public function setStartDateAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['start_date'] = Carbon::now()->addMonth();
    }
```

put the above function into your model and after that you  dont need to set the date for each insertion.

For more information 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to add multiple tasks then always use loop**. hope following code will help you..

```
// Array of tasks
$task_array = [
    [
        "text" => 'Velo',
        "role_id" => 1,
        "progress" => 0.0,
        "duration" => 1,
        "parent" => 0,
        "type" => "project",
        "color" => '#ccc'
    ],
    [
        "text" => 'Auto',
        "role_id" => 1,
        "progress" => 0.0,
        "duration" => 1,
        "parent" => 0,
        "type" => "project",
        "color" => '#ccc'
    ]
];


// Loop to save tasks from task_list
foreach ($task_array as $task) {
    $tasks = new Task();
    $tasks->text = $task["text"]
    $tasks->role_id = $task["role_id"]
    $tasks->progress = $task["progress"]
    $tasks->duration = $task["duration"]
    $tasks->parent = $task["parent"]
    $tasks->type = $task["type"]
    $tasks->color = $task["color"]

    // Next month date from now
    $next_month_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 month'));
    $tasks->start_date = $next_month_date;

    // Save Task
    $tasks->save();
}
```